# How is the Taylor expansion used in this case?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a problem to understand the Taylor expansion in a specific case I will describe now, but first the context.

Given the following Theorem:
Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $\tilde{x} \in D$.
If $\tilde{x}$ is a local minimum of a unconstrained problem without, then, in addition to $\nabla f(\tilde{x}) = 0$ it holds that $h^T f''(\tilde{x})h \ge 0$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ i.e.,
$f''(\tilde{x})$ is positive semidefinite.

A proof sketch goes like this:

Take $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary and consider $f(\tilde{x} + th)$ for $t$ small, we know using Taylor' theorem
$$f(\tilde{x} +th) -f(\tilde{x}) = t \nabla f(\tilde{x})^Th + \frac{1}{2} t^2h^Tf''(\tilde{x} + \epsilon h) h$$ for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ ...  I don't want do go further.

My problem is the equation, especially I don't understand how the Taylor formula is used and where the $t$ in the first derivative $t \nabla f(\tilde{x})^Th$ comes from.

I hope my question is clear, if not please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the definition of the taylor expansion of a function $g(t)$ around $t=0$:
$$
g(t) = g(0) + tg'(0) + \frac{1}{2}t^2g''(0) + o(t^2) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{A})
$$
where the "higher order" terms $o(t^2)$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{o(t^2)}{t^2}=0$. Note that in equation (A) we have equality since we added the term $o(t^2)$, otherwise we would write $\approx$ instead (compare with what you wrote).

Now, define $g(t) = f(\tilde{x} + th)$ where $\tilde{x}, h$ are vectors defined as in your question. By the chain rule we have:
$$
g'(0) = \nabla f(\tilde{x} + th)^Th|_{t=0} = \nabla f(\tilde{x})^Th
$$
and
$$
g''(0) = h^Tf''(\tilde{x})h
$$
where $f''(\tilde{x})$ is the hessian matrix of $f$ usually denoted as $\nabla^2 f(\tilde{x})$ in other texts. Now, use these expresions of $g'(0), g''(0)$ as well as $g(0)=f(\tilde{x})$ in equation (A):
$$
f(\tilde{x}+th) = g(t) = f(\tilde{x}) + t\nabla f(\tilde{x})^Th + \frac{1}{2}t^2h^Tf''(\tilde{x})h + o(t^2)
$$
or rewriting:
$$
f(\tilde{x}+th) - f(\tilde{x}) = t\nabla f(\tilde{x})^Th + \frac{1}{2}t^2h^Tf''(\tilde{x})h + o(t^2)
$$
compare this with what you have. These are equivalent expressions, except for  what I believe its a typo in the variable $\epsilon$ which should have been $t$ instead (and would not appear)  in the term $\frac{1}{2}t^2h^Tf''(\tilde{x})h$. Besides, I included the term $o(t^2)$. Otherwise what you wrote does not make much sense.

Up to now, I think this answers how was the Taylor formula used, and where does the $t$ comes from in the first derivative.

Now, if the text/reference you are reading/consulting does not include the $o(t^2)$ term for some reason. Don't worry, continue the proof as intended: use $\nabla f(\tilde{x})=0$, divide by $t^2$ and make $t\to 0$ at the end, using the fact that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{o(t^2)}{t^2}=0$.

If you want more details for the proof of this theorem, I took these steps from Proposition 1.1.1 (page 14) in the Nonlinear Programming book (Second edition) by Dimitri Bertsekas.

I hope this helps!